# Database: How to model these SQL relations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-relationship

Entities

1. AutoShop
2. Supplier
3. SupplierType
4. Car

For the sake of this example:

1. An autoshop has multiple suppliers of multiple types;
2. A specific supplier can be of multiple types;
3. A specific car can be supplied by multiple suppliers of a specific type;

What I have in mind:

```
CREATE TABLE [AutoShop] (
    [Id]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoShop] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [Supplier] (
    [Id]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Supplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [SupplierType] (
    [Id]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SupplierType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [Car] (
    [Id]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]              NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Car] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

-- an autoshop can have multiple suppliers of different types, 
-- providing multiple products
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutoShopSupplier] (    
    [AutoShopId]  INT NOT NULL,
    [SupplierId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SupplierTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoShopSupplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AutoShopId] ASC, [SupplierId] ASC, [SupplierTypeId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplier_ToAutoShop] FOREIGN KEY ([AutoShopId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AutoShop] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplier_ToSupplier] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierType_ToSupplierType] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SupplierType] ([Id])
);

-- multiple cars can be supplied by multiple suppliers, but just from a specific type of supplier
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutoShopSupplierCar] (    
    [AutoShopId]  INT NOT NULL,
    [SupplierId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SupplierTypeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [CarId] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoShopSupplierCar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AutoShopId] ASC, [SupplierId] ASC, [SupplierTypeId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierCar_ToAutoShop] FOREIGN KEY ([AutoShopId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AutoShop] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierCar_ToSupplier] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierCar_ToSupplierType] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SupplierType] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierCar_ToCar] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SupplierType] ([Id])
);
```

Is this the right way?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: I wouldnt have the autoshopsupplier. You simply need to add those foreign keys to your other 4 tables

Comment: What you are creating is called s star schema, which makes sense for reporting purposes but not so much for an application database. Add the SupplierTypeID to the Supplier table. Add the SupplierID to the CarID. This should work.

Comment: @Bave Sorry, I've edited the question...because a Supplier can be of multiple types, which means that I can't add SupplierTypeID to Supplier, right? And also, a Car can be supplied by multiple Suppliers...

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Does it still make sense with the new requirements I've added to the question?

Comment: You're creating foreign key tables when really you should add the foreign keys to your original 4 tables. That is proper practice

Comment: @Johnny OK, but in that case, if you have a n-m connection, you could use a bridge table which only contains foreign keys from each table.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Thanks Ryan. But adding the foreign keys will not meet the requirements I need...

Comment: @Bave Using a bridge table was my hunch...but the problem is that an autoshop can have multiple suppliers and just for a specific type, I need to register the id of the car they supplied...

Comment: @Johnny I think you have to draw a diagram and post it here, so we can really help you. I think visualizing might make this more understandable for everyone.

Comment: @Bave you're just making your life more complicated by having a foreign key table.

Answer (score 0):

I siplified your script a little bit and added some table

```
CREATE TABLE [AutoShop] (
    [Id]      INT   PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL);
go
CREATE TABLE [Supplier] (
    [Id]     INT    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL);
go
CREATE TABLE [SupplierType] (
    [Id]     INT    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL);
go
CREATE TABLE [Car] (
    [Id]     INT    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [Name]   NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL);
go
CREATE TABLE [SupplierTypeSupplier] (
    [SupplierId]     INT,
    [SupplierTypeID]   INT,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SupplierTypeSupplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SupplierId] , [SupplierTypeID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Supplier] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SupplierType] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SupplierType] ([Id]));
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutoShopSupplier] (    
    [AutoShopId]  INT,
    [SupplierId] INT,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoShopSupplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AutoShopId] , [SupplierId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierAutoShop] FOREIGN KEY ([AutoShopId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AutoShop] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierSupplier] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([Id]));
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CarSupplier] ( 
    [SupplierId] INT,  
    [CarId]  INT,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CarSupplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CarId] , [SupplierId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CarSupplierCar] FOREIGN KEY ([CarId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Car] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CarSupplierSupplier] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([Id]));
```

You don't need to use NOT NULL when using key work PRIMARY KEY
and you don't have to write PRIMEY KEY as a CONSTRAINT if you are using only one primary key

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input Jurgen, your tips are very helpful! However, the business logic demands that a specific AutoShop can be supplied by the same Supplier of different types... Imagine a supplier that provides 'exhaust pipes' and at the same time can provide 'windshields' (two different types of suppliers). Furthermore, it's important to register the 'windshield's ids' that are supplied to an AutoShop by each 'windshield supplier'.

Comment: @Johnny You will need something like this (posting as a new comment)

Answer (score 0):

@Jonny

```
CREATE TABLE [Product] (
[Id]     INT    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
[Name]   NVARCHAR (200) NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AutoShopSupplierSuppliment] (    
[AutoShopId]  INT,
[SupplierId] INT,
[ProductId] INT,
[Date] DATE,
[Quantity] INT,

CONSTRAINT [PK_AutoShopSupplier] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AutoShopId] , [SupplierId],[ProductId]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierAutoShop] FOREIGN KEY ([AutoShopId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AutoShop] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierSupplier] FOREIGN KEY ([SupplierId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Supplier] ([Id])),
CONSTRAINT [FK_AutoShopSupplierProduct] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([Id]));
```

You can use Date column to separate the records etc.